# Get previous value of current row in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am calculating value based on value in previous row. I used `LAG` for getting value from previous row and it works well for first two but not for next rows. Let me elaborate my scenario if row is first then I am taking `Open_HA` same as `O` column. But for next rows I am taking previous row `Open_HA` and adding it to previous row `Close_HA` to calculate the next row `Open_HA` and dividing it by 2 and so on. What I have done is below.

```
DECLARE @StockIndicator AS TABLE
(
Sr INT IDENTITY,
StartDate DATE,
O decimal(18,3),
H decimal(18,3),    
L decimal(18,3),    
C decimal(18,3),
Close_HA AS (O+H+L+C)/4
)
                                                                                                   
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-15',  93.25   ,93.30  ,93.30  ,93.25 )
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-16',  98.55   ,98.55  ,98.55  ,98.55 )
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-17',  100.98  ,99.99  ,100.98 ,99.99 )
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-18',  102.05  ,102.05 ,102.05 ,102.05)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-19',  103.00  ,103.90 ,103.90 ,103.00)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-20',  104.08  ,104.23 ,104.23 ,104.08)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-21',  104.90  ,104.60 ,105.00 ,104.00)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-22',  104.60  ,104.60 ,104.60 ,104.60)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-23',  105.90  ,105.90 ,105.90 ,105.90)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-24',  104.40  ,104.40 ,105.00 ,103.51)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-25',  105.18  ,105.18 ,105.18 ,105.18)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-26',  103.00  ,102.60 ,103.52 ,102.60)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-27',  100.00  ,100.00 ,100.00 ,100.00)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-28',  99.40   ,98.95  ,99.78  ,98.95 )
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-29',  99.00   ,99.00  ,99.00  ,99.00 )
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-09-30',  100.01  ,100.90 ,101.00 ,100.01)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-10-01',  102.00  ,102.70 ,102.70 ,102.00)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-10-02',  102.70  ,102.00 ,102.70 ,102.00)
INSERT INTO @StockIndicator(StartDate,O,H,L,C)VALUES('2020-10-03',  103.30  ,103.30 ,103.30 ,103.30)


SELECT Sr,
       O,
       H,
       L,
       C,
       CASE
            WHEN OuterDetail.Sr > 1 THEN ((LAG(OuterDetail.Open_HA) OVER (ORDER BY OuterDetail.Sr)) + (LAG(OuterDetail.[Close_HA]) OVER (ORDER BY OuterDetail.Sr))) / 2
            ELSE OuterDetail.Open_HA
       END AS Open_HA,
       [Close_HA]
FROM (SELECT Sr,
             O,
             H,
             L,
             C,
             CASE WHEN Detail.Sr = 1 THEN Detail.O ELSE 0 END AS Open_HA,
             [Close_HA]
      FROM (SELECT Sr, O, H, L, C, [Close_HA] FROM @StockIndicator) Detail ) OuterDetail;
```

Expected result should be like below image

[image]

For more clarification [excel link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KgW03BH5YamMH5wgLku94iFShe4xoECc/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115198500700002190903&rtpof=true&sd=true) that doing accurate calculation as I am trying to do with above query.

Comment: So, for your sample data, what is your expected results? Also, why all those nested `SELECT`'s? They really aren't needed.

Comment: Where are your primary key and your natural keys? Without those, you must make assumptions about the rows that are easily (and usually) violated and that will cause whatever solution you devise to fail. You also make significant assumption about how Sr is populated - one that I suggest is inappropriate.

Comment: @Larnu expected result is that i have to add Open_HA and  Close_HA of previous row and divide it by 2 to get the current row Open_HA  and so for all rows

Comment: Put your actual expected results in your question, @AzeemHafeez .

Comment: @Larnu I just add the snapshot of expected result

Comment: If the information is important, it should be in the question, @AzeemHafeez , not on an external site.

Comment: @Larnu important information already given but link is just for clarification how to perform calculation as I am trying with query. I don't know way to paste excel data here with formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with recursion to perform the non-trivial running calculation related to the prior row.

[The fiddle for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87ea2bdf0e5e6386e08b14a445dea2c0)

First we calculate `Close_HA` in the first CTE term, then we recursively use that result to calculate `Open_HA`.

If you've already calculated `Close_HA` (it's already in the table), we can skip the first CTE term.

The SQL:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *
             , (O + H + L + C)/4 AS Close_HA
          FROM test
     )
   , calc AS (
        SELECT t1.*, C AS Open_HA FROM cte AS t1 WHERE Sr = 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT t1.*
             , CAST((t2.Close_HA + t2.Open_HA) / 2.0 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
          FROM cte  AS t1
          JOIN calc AS t2
            ON t1.Sr = t2.Sr + 1
     )
SELECT * FROM calc ORDER BY Sr
;
```

The result:

```
+------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+---------+
| Sr   | Date       | O      | H      | L      | C      | Close_HA   | Open_HA |
+------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 2020-09-15 |  93.25 |  93.30 |  93.30 |  93.25 |  93.275000 |   93.25 |
|    2 | 2020-09-16 |  98.55 |  98.55 |  98.55 |  98.55 |  98.550000 |   93.26 |
|    3 | 2020-09-17 | 100.98 |  99.99 | 100.98 |  99.99 | 100.485000 |   95.91 |
|    4 | 2020-09-18 | 102.05 | 102.05 | 102.05 | 102.05 | 102.050000 |   98.20 |
|    5 | 2020-09-19 | 103.00 | 103.90 | 103.90 | 103.00 | 103.450000 |  100.13 |
|    6 | 2020-09-20 | 104.08 | 104.23 | 104.23 | 104.08 | 104.155000 |  101.79 |
|    7 | 2020-09-21 | 104.90 | 104.60 | 105.00 | 104.00 | 104.625000 |  102.97 |
|    8 | 2020-09-22 | 104.60 | 104.60 | 104.60 | 104.60 | 104.600000 |  103.80 |
|    9 | 2020-09-23 | 105.90 | 105.90 | 105.90 | 105.90 | 105.900000 |  104.20 |
|   10 | 2020-09-24 | 104.40 | 104.40 | 105.00 | 103.51 | 104.327500 |  105.05 |
|   11 | 2020-09-25 | 105.18 | 105.18 | 105.18 | 105.18 | 105.180000 |  104.69 |
|   12 | 2020-09-26 | 103.00 | 102.60 | 103.52 | 102.60 | 102.930000 |  104.94 |
|   13 | 2020-09-27 | 100.00 | 100.00 | 100.00 | 100.00 | 100.000000 |  103.94 |
|   14 | 2020-09-28 |  99.40 |  98.95 |  99.78 |  98.95 |  99.270000 |  101.97 |
|   15 | 2020-09-29 |  99.00 |  99.00 |  99.00 |  99.00 |  99.000000 |  100.62 |
|   16 | 2020-09-30 | 100.01 | 100.90 | 101.00 | 100.01 | 100.480000 |   99.81 |
|   17 | 2020-10-01 | 102.00 | 102.70 | 102.70 | 102.00 | 102.350000 |  100.15 |
|   18 | 2020-10-02 | 102.70 | 102.00 | 102.70 | 102.00 | 102.350000 |  101.25 |
|   19 | 2020-10-03 | 103.30 | 103.30 | 103.30 | 103.30 | 103.300000 |  101.80 |
+------+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+---------+
```

Setup for the test case:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    Sr     int
  , Date   Date
  , O      DECIMAL(8,2)
  , H      DECIMAL(8,2)
  , L      DECIMAL(8,2)
  , C      DECIMAL(8,2)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ( 1,'2020-09-15', 93.25, 93.30, 93.30, 93.25)
, ( 2,'2020-09-16', 98.55, 98.55, 98.55, 98.55)
, ( 3,'2020-09-17',100.98, 99.99,100.98, 99.99)
, ( 4,'2020-09-18',102.05,102.05,102.05,102.05)
, ( 5,'2020-09-19',103.00,103.90,103.90,103.00)
, ( 6,'2020-09-20',104.08,104.23,104.23,104.08)
, ( 7,'2020-09-21',104.90,104.60,105.00,104.00)
, ( 8,'2020-09-22',104.60,104.60,104.60,104.60)
, ( 9,'2020-09-23',105.90,105.90,105.90,105.90)
, (10,'2020-09-24',104.40,104.40,105.00,103.51)
, (11,'2020-09-25',105.18,105.18,105.18,105.18)
, (12,'2020-09-26',103.00,102.60,103.52,102.60)
, (13,'2020-09-27',100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00)
, (14,'2020-09-28', 99.40, 98.95, 99.78, 98.95)
, (15,'2020-09-29', 99.00, 99.00, 99.00, 99.00)
, (16,'2020-09-30',100.01,100.90,101.00,100.01)
, (17,'2020-10-01',102.00,102.70,102.70,102.00)
, (18,'2020-10-02',102.70,102.00,102.70,102.00)
, (19,'2020-10-03',103.30,103.30,103.30,103.30)
;
```

Comment: it works. Thanks for your time and showing interest in this

Answer (score 0):

As the row you are calculating uses the result from it's formula for the last row, it's not operating over the result set, but it's being dynamically created row by row, so the lag function won't work here. What you can do is use a cursor to populate that column:

```
DECLARE @StockIndicator AS TABLE
(
Sr INT IDENTITY,
StartDate DATE,
O decimal(18,3),
H decimal(18,3),    
L decimal(18,3),    
C decimal(18,3),
Open_HA decimal(18,3), -- I've added the column to the temp variable
Close_HA AS (O+H+L+C)/4
)
```

```
declare @sr int, @close_ha decimal(18,3), @O decimal(18,3)
declare @last_close_ha decimal(18,3), @last_open_ha decimal(18,3)

declare cur cursor local FOR
    select Sr, Close_HA, O
    from @StockIndicator
    order by Sr asc
for update of Open_HA

open cur
fetch next from cur into @sr, @close_ha, @o
while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    set @last_open_ha = case @Sr
        when 1 then @O
        else (@last_open_ha+@last_close_ha)/2
    end
    set @last_close_ha = @close_ha
    update @StockIndicator set
    Open_HA = @last_open_ha
    where Sr=@Sr
    fetch next from cur into @sr, @close_ha, @o
end
close cur
deallocate cur
select *
from @StockIndicator
```

You can see it working on DB Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b15550c331b6df6d350200c0af880e8).